# Why is split and join doing this?

Tags: javascript

I'm getting some very weird behaviour that I don't understand using JavaScript split and join. I'm sending names with spaces in an API call but using %3 as the delimiter for spaces, as in, if I'm sending `"Ammar Ahmed"`, the API call would look like: `api/v1?q=Ammar%3Ahmed`. In the server code, when I split it up again with `q.split("%3").join(" ")` because the database contains names with spaces, for one name in particular: `"Ashwini Bettahalsoor"`, I'm getting `"Ashwini;ettahalsoor"`. I'm very confused why its doing this, its splitting it including the B and joining it with a ; but it works perfectly normal for all names that the last name does not start with B. I'm sure it has something to do with the letter B but first of all I'm curious as to why this is happening and secondly, I'm wondering what I should use instead of `%3` for spaces in the API call.

Comment: [Percent encoding](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/percent-encoding) takes three characters, `%3A`, `%3B` etc.

Comment: Why are you using `%3` to represent space? Why not the usual `%20`?

Comment: Or you could even use `+` in a url. Please stick to standard URL encoding. Do you even need to manually encode it?

Comment: You generally shouldn't need to deal with percent-encoding yourself, most middleware decodes it automatically. In JS, use `encodeURIComponent()` to create the encoded URI parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%3` is not the correct encoding for a space. You're getting `;` because `%3B` is the encoding for that character. URI encoding always uses 2 hex digits.

You should use `encodeURICompnent()` to generate the correct encoding.

```
let url = 'api/v1?q=' + encodeURIComponent('Ashwini Bettahalsoor');
```

And on the server you should use middleware that decodes the query parameters for you, rather than using `split()` and `join()` explicitly.